# How can I create an ECG digram chart html ? I am using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, charts, ecgi

I'm trying to plot an ECG chart using Chart.js. I'm feeding the chart with simulated ECG data points. However, the resulting chart doesn't display the characteristic peaks and valleys of an ECG waveform. The y-axis scale seems inaccurate as well.

I expect the chart to show the typical ECG waveform with clear P, QRS, and T waves. The y-axis should represent voltage in millivolts (mV). However, the current chart looks more like a sine wave, and the voltage scale seems off.

I've tried adjusting the y-axis scale but haven't been able to achieve the desired result. Any suggestions on how to create a more accurate ECG chart?